# Sending cookies/sessions to subdomains

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, cookies, session-cookies

As the title says, I'm trying to set cookies/sessions on the browser.

---

***To preface***:

Frontend: `https://www.example.com`

Backend: `https://api.example.com`

Frontend makes a request to the backend, the backend creates a session, and a cookie is sent back to the frontend in the response.

---

***Problem:***

The request is successful and the response shows that there is a session, however it was not set. The error message is as follows:

> This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url.

---

***Research:***

Based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/3100570) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55881333/3100570), it appears that:

> cookies can be shared is that both domains have the same main-domain

Which is the case for my scenario. The main domain is `example.com` and the subdomains are `www.example.com` and `api.example.com`.

In addition, [Mozilla official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) states that:

> if a domain is specified, then subdomains are always included

---

***Implementation***

The frontend is developed in ***React*** and the backend is developed in ***Python (Flask)***. Both are hosted ***Heroku***. Domain registrar is with ***GoDaddy*** and I'm using ***Cloudflare*** as my DNS to re-route traffic and setting the correct domains.

A sample request looks like this:

```
const headers = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken 
};
...
const handleFormSubmission = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post('https://backend.com/add-results', { tokenId: tokenId }, { withCredentials: true, headers: headers })
}
```

And the backend has the following settings:

```
...
    CORS(app, origins=["https://www.example.com"], expose_headers=["Content-Type", "X-CSRFToken"], supports_credentials=True)  
...
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True
    app.config['REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
    app.config['REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN'] = 'example.com'
```

Was wondering if anyone has experienced a similar problem and found a solution. I got the idea of using subdomains from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70627684/flask-sessions-not-persistent-between-requests-from-cross-domains/70627992#70627992), but I have had no luck with my implementation.

---

Here's a screen shot of what I'm getting

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was actually pretty simple:

```
    CORS(app, origins=["https://www.example.com", "https://example.com"], expose_headers=["Content-Type", "X-CSRFToken"], supports_credentials=True)  

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True
    app.config['REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
    app.config['REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN'] = '.example.com'
    app.config['WTF_CSRF_SSL_STRICT'] = False
```

Main changes were:

> app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'

And:

> app.config['WTF_CSRF_SSL_STRICT'] = False

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE needed to be 'None' to avoid the default value of 'Lax' which would prevent the cookie from being received and set on the browser.

WTF_CSRF_SSL_STRICT was set to false because the origins of the request and the server needed to be the same (same origin policy). However, I have configured a whitelist of allowed origins in my CORS configuration. That said, I think that covers that case.

Also, I cleared my caches on my browser and the DNS. In addition, I restarted my servers where the frontend and backend were hosted.

Hopes this helps others, cheers!

Comment: I have this and it works for me

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret_key'
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
```

Comment: you could share here  your code in github , please?